# How to programmatically add view on layout clicked position?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-view

how to create view in the place where the layout is clicked?
Something like this in the picture:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VWIX.png)

The table is constructed from relative layouts for each days.

```
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/calendarScrollView"
    ...... >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarSplitterRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:padding="0dp" >
        .......
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mondayRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <include layout="@layout/calendar_zebra" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tuesdayRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" >

            <include layout="@layout/calendar_zebra" />

            <com.example.admin.nuschedule.view.LessonEventView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:lessonName="CSCI 321"
                app:lessonRoom="7.257"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
           .......

    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Actually, I guess that i should listen for relativelayout click and add new view progmatically

Can anyone now how to implement that in code?

Comment: you are thinking it correct

Comment: read the click on the box and add a new view or layout inside it